# Best solution for running unsafe JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, v8

I've got a scenario. Users are to be able to run applications written in JavaScript. They are completely unmoderated. I **must not** allow any way to interact with the underlying system. My first thought was to use something like `vm2` to isolate the code. My issue with this is the NodeJS overhead. I'd ideally run this with as little space in between as possible.

I had considered writing an interface to the v8 JavaScript engine, which can fetch and execute scripts, however, this approach would lose the libuv integration found in NodeJS, which will be critical for the effectiveness of my system.

My question: What is the best way to guarantee execution safety, with as little performance loss, while retaining NodeJS-like execution conditions (namely the asynchronous nature of IO and structure of the event loop)? As an added bonus, I will need to redefine the `import`/`export` behaviour, without requiring an array of command-line flags or `package.json` options.

I don't mind C++ scripting, so any suggestions involving that are most welcome.
Thanks so much for the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "guarantee" anything, then you need a layer to restrict the options to a finite space that you do not care about, and this layer will cost something. Some ideas:

1. In the browser, ideally the user's. Browsers regularly run unrestricted JS that can do nearly anything, and have produced better sandboxes than you can to stop that JS from taking over the rest of the machine.
2. In a heavily restricted container, ideally rebuilt each time with no persistent file storage and [extra measures](https://dev.to/narasimha1997/building-a-secure-sandboxed-environment-for-executing-untrusted-code-7e8) for kernel isolation. I still don't trust it, but there are Docker images that advertise untrusted execution, so maybe.
3. Virtual machine - heavier, but more reliably isolated.
4. vm2 or other runtime layer: leaving less room for people to get clever by restricting the language itself.
5. Compiling layer: run the user input through a parser that will fail on any command/module outside your whitelist. While there are plenty of JS supersets/transpilersscripts/frameworks, I don't know one that restricts like this, and do not recommend rolling your own due to the variety of ways to obfuscate malicious code.

Safety will still be relative: restrictions might prevent JS from affecting the host, while still allowing a DDoS against a remote system.

Comment: I'd say your advice about safety being relative is valid. Ultimately, my goal is to force applications through a regulated layer, such that access to system resources can be controlled. Perhaps vm2 is the best option after all. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: A parser is probably not a good place for security as projects like jsfuck demonstrate.

Comment: I didn't want to say it, but I agree